# Laravel API Registration

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0

I am developing a laravel back-end to work with Vue JS, and trying to implement user registration. I have downloaded  passport to authenticate users, but I am having trouble understanding exactly how a new user registers for the website.

From the research I have done it seems like you would want to make a route for the registration  that can be accessed without using laravel passport, and then once the user is created  grant it a token.

Once the user is registered Would I use a personal grant token, Implicit, or use passports CreateFreshApiToken middleware.

Should I put all my routes in web or the api route file?

Answer (score 7):

You may create a route in your api where anybody can register a new user , so y af sadfdsadsasadfdsaou do not use any auth middlewares, like for example:

```
Route::post('users', 'AuthController@register'); // Signup
```

and in your controller the related method:

```
/**
 * API Registerx
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $rules = [
        'name' => 'unique:users|required',
        'email'    => 'unique:users|required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ];

    $input     = $request->only('name', 'email','password');
    $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['success' => false, 'error' => $validator->messages()]);
    }
    $name = $request->name;
    $email    = $request->email;
    $password = $request->password;
    $user     = User::create(['name' => $name, 'email' => $email, 'password' => Hash::make($password)]);
    
}
```

from this point the type of passport OAuth2 authorization code flow you choose will influence your implementation on the consumer app.

You may go for the classical OAuth2 flow where basically you have this steps:

1. Register the consumer application to the OAuth2 server and obtain the Client Id and Secret
2. The consumer application request an authorization code to the OAuth2 server using the Client Id and Secret
3. Once obtained the authorization code the consumer application can now request an access token to the OAuth2 server
4. The consumer application can now have access to the Api using in every request to the server its access token that it is sent in the header request.

Obviously each step above is an HTTP request and how you do it depends on the technology you use in the consumer application.

For example in php, you can use Guzzle and send an access token request like this:

```
 $http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;

    $response = $http->post('http://yourserver.com/oauth/token', [
        'form_params' => [
              'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
              'client_id' => 'client-id',
              'client_secret' => 'client-secret',
              'redirect_uri' => 'http://example.com/callback',
              'code' => $request->code,
        ],
    ]);
```

On the other side you may want to use a simpler way to retrieve access tokens, avoiding all the authorization code request etc. using [Laravel passport Personal Access Tokens](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#personal-access-tokens). In this way you can issue access tokens for the user simply doing:

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

// Creating a token without scopes...
$token = $user->createToken('Token Name')->accessToken;
```

I encourage you to take a look to the Passport Laravel documentation and check all the possibilities offered.